# Laravel 5.0 saving image with custom disk result in error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to upload an image and store it in a certain location using a custom disk defined in the filesystems like this:

```
'blockcontentimages' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path() . '/static/core/img/templates',
],
```

In my controller I do this:

```
$image = $request->file('content');

$file = $image->getClientOriginalName();

Storage::disk('blockcontentimages')->put('filename', $file);
```

But I get the following error:

> ErrorException in FilesystemManager.php line 230:
>
> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter' does not have a method 'createDriver'

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here

Comment: I don't think it'll solve the issue but shouldn't it be `->put($file, $image)`?

Answer (score 0):

Second argument of `put` method is the file content, why are you passing the original name?

See [Official Storage doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#obtaining-disk-instances)

Change with that :

```php
$image = $request->file('content');
Storage::disk('blockcontentimages')->put('filename', $file);
```

Comment: I changed it and unfortunately it gives the same error